# Cocoa-Touch - Make a read-only UITextField become first responder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have a `UITextField` which I have set it's `inputView` to be of a `UIPickerView` so the user can choose between a few values there. However I'm having trouble making the textfield become first responder.

If I set my textfield `userInteractionEnabled = NO` then it won't become first responder but if I set it to `YES` it will become first responder but then I will have a blinking cursor in there which I do not want. So how to make a read-only `UITextField` become first responder?

Comment: Why not use a UILabel and have the picker be the first responder?

Comment: You can't assign `inputView` to a `UILabel`

Comment: Sure, and there's no need to. Bring up a picker, by whatever means works in your app, and the populate the UILabel from the pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: delegate method. It might be the only way to go, if it's not possible to make a read-only text field the first responder.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks you dont need a `UITextField`. So an alternative way to achieve this is to have a `UILabel` with a `UIButton` added on top, which will bring the picker. On selection of any value in picker, the `UILabel` text can be modified.